# Calculating time dilation from a solution to the Dirac equation

Tags: time-dilation, dirac-equation

Suppose I have a Muon in a potential well. Its wavefunction is a solution of the [Dirac equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation), a relativistic version of the Schrodinger equation for spin 1/2 particles.

Because the particle is "moving" it should have longer half-life than a free muon. But how much longer?

Suppose I use the momentum operator to compute the four-momemtum $p$ at each point. From this I could calculate the velocity and the time passage rate $d\tau/dt$ at each point using special relativity. Then I could compute a weighted integral of the flux: $1/x=\int p_t^2 d\tau/dt$. Would $xt_{1/2}$ give the new half-life?

Comment: Not an expert, but would you not have to couple muon, electron and neutriono fields to adequately model decay?

Answer (score 0):

For potential wells big enough to function sensibly as a potential well, it probably does not matter.

I am not claiming the following to be gospel, but you can try a few estimates. For example, consider an infinite square well, in which case the energy eigenstates are sines of one single momentum magnitude each (i.e. symmetrically either $+p$ or $-p$). Then you have just one single time dilation factor to consider, and you can check that the lowest energy eigenstates have a time dilation factor so small as to be ignorable.

Beyond that, I think we will not have single-momentum-magnitude eigenstates, and then it becomes complicated. If you can have the energy eigenstate, I think you can compute the kinetic energy expectation value for each energy eigenstate, and use that for the time dilation. I just don't think that finding the momentum wavefunction and then time dilating each momentum separately would be a suitable thing to do.